# How to add a 2nd header to a DataGrid?

Tags: asp.net, .net, datagrid

Is there a way to add a 2nd header row to a DataGrid? In the row I want a DropdDownList and a Label. Right now I have a BoundColumn and a TemplateColumn in my Columns section of the grid. But adding something here will only add column, but not a header.

It should look like this:

This is my label text: *dropdownlist* --> first row of header
Amount          Link --> 2nd row of header
100                link1
200                link2

How could I do this?

Thanks :)

Comment: And why does it need to be in the DataGrid?  Why not just put it before the DataGrid?

Comment: Yeah, that would work, but I want it in the Grid...not possible that easily?

Comment: Does it have to _be_ in the grid or can it just _look_ _like_ it's in the grid?  Adding it before the grid with a little styling (wrapping it all in a table, even) can accomplish that just fine.  Alternatively, you can ditch the grid and do a little more manual work to customize it a lot.

Comment: Ignore my previous post about the HeaderTemplate.  That's for a single column only.  I don't think you can do it with a DataGrid, but you could certainly do it with a repeater, and use the Repeater to generate a table.  The easiest method would be to just pt it before.

Comment: I placed it right before the grid, looks nice as well...I think there was an easy way to add it :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

check the links

[Add an extra header to the ASP.NET DataGrid](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/add_an_extra_header_to_th.aspx)

[DataGrid - adding an extra header...](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t94620-datagrid-adding-an-extra-header.html)